# Why css height 100% is not applying for normal div?

Tags: css

This is my simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div{height:100%;width:100%;background:red;position:relative;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS height 100% is not applying for DIV.

I know some other css code to obtain this. But why this code is not working. how to work on height 100% and width 100% without any script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `%` to work you need to set height for `parent element` as well.

Set `html, body {height: 100%}`

From the Docs -

> The  is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly, the value computes to auto. A percentage height
>   on the root element (e.g. ) is relative to the initial
>   containing block (whose dimensions are equal to the dimensions of the
>   viewport).

Check more on this at - [MDN Percent Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)

So in your case, you can do like this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html,body{height:100%;}
        div{height:100%;width:100%;background:red;position:relative;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using `position:aboslute;`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgeRM/)

```
div {
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
body {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Alternatively you can set `html` and `body` height also to 100%, if going this route be sure to strip the margin from body.

[jsFiddle (with margin, notice scrollbars)](http://jsfiddle.net/pgeRM/1/)
[jsFiddle (without margin)](http://jsfiddle.net/pgeRM/2/)

```
html, 
body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```