# css inline style height 100% is not applying for div

Tags: jquery, html, css

In html I assigned div height as `100%` in inline css,when loading height of `div` is changed as 0. Why its happen?
refer this 
http://jsfiddle.net/CLjH3/3/

This is my code sample:

```js
display();

function display() {
  var elementHeight = $("#container").height();

  alert("ElementHeight :" + elementHeight);

  var elementWidth = $("#container").width();

  alert("ElementWidth :" + elementWidth);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:solid 1px red;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `body` and `html` height:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/CLjH3/4/)**</kbd>

In order for a percentage value to work for height, the parent's height must be determined. The only exception is the **root** element `<html>`, which can be a percentage height. .

So, you've given all of your elements height, except for the `<html>`, so what you should do is add this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

From the Docs -

> The  is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly, the value computes to auto. A percentage height
>   on the root element (e.g. ) is relative to the initial
>   containing block (whose dimensions are equal to the dimensions of the
>   viewport).

Check more on this at - [MDN Percent Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)

sources [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417083/why-css-height-100-is-not-applying-for-normal-div) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262852/css-height-in-percent-not-working)